# Custom shaped text box in windows forms?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to insert a custom shaped `TextBox` like an oval or a triangle `TextBox` or `Label` or any `Control` in win forms.

I tried telerik textbox controls and c1 controls but couldn't find any shaped control.

By the way can I add a rectangle or a line or any other shape in windows forms just like in ms power point and type text into it and format it and so on, change its size and use as a control which has the same properties of a win control?

I tried the above but could't get it.

thanks!

Comment: `I tried the above but could't get it.` Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: You can make the textbox invisible (except for the cursor) and use the background of the (parent) form.

Furthermore: why do you want to dos this?

Comment: You can play with `Control.Region`

Comment: tnw - adding a control does not need attempt if you mean to include code. I think I should Install wpf if no other choice - SLaks. I want to do this to look nice!

Comment: WPF is part of .Net.  You don't need to install anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an [article with example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) that discusses the region property that can be used to shape a control.